# Image_transport warning of unsyncronization

Tags: python, image-transport

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello.

I am trying to use the package [depthimage_to_laserscan](http://wiki.ros.org/depthimage_to_laserscan). My launch file to do this is the following:

```
 <node pkg="depthimage_to_laserscan" type="depthimage_to_laserscan" name="depthimage_to_laserscan">
    <remap from="image" to="/camera/depth/image"/>
    <remap from="camera_info" to="/camera/depth/camera_info"/>
  </node>
```

The problem comes when y launch it and am image_transport warn appears:

```
[ WARN] [1619004832.858784407]: [image_transport] Topics '/camera/depth/image' and '/camera/depth/camera_info' do not appear to be synchronized. In the last 10s:
    Image messages received:      75
    CameraInfo messages received: 75
    Synchronized pairs:           0
```

I have tried to use the `ApproximateTimeSynchronizer` to syncronize these topics, but with this, they still don't syncronize. this is my file to use the syncronizer:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import rospy
import message_filters
from sensor_msgs.msg import Image
from sensor_msgs.msg import CameraInfo

rospy.init_node('sync_node')
rospy.loginfo("Sync started")

def callback(image_raw, image_info):
    print("callback")

image_raw = message_filters.Subscriber('/camera/depth/image', Image)
image_info = message_filters.Subscriber('/camera/depth/camera_info', CameraInfo)
ts = message_filters.ApproximateTimeSynchronizer([image_raw, image_info], 10, 0.01, allow_headerless=True)
ts.registerCallback(callback)
rospy.spin()
```

Checking the header of both topics, the stamp is almost equal (difference of 1-3 ms).

What is wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Best regards.
Alessandro

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/376630/image_transport-warning-of-unsyncronization/) by [Alessandro Melino](https://answers.ros.org/users/52370/alessandro-melino/) on ROS Answers with karma: 113 on 2021-04-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [OzzieTheHead](https://answers.ros.org/users/13406/ozziethehead/) on 2021-05-06**:
Your `Image` and `CameraInfo` topics are at 7.5hz. Is this intentional or is something bottlenecking?

When you run this node do you see "callback" printed? (If you are using roslaunch don't forget `output:="screen"` for the node)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The unsyncronization is due to the low processing power of the computer. With other computers or a GPU/TPU the framerate and the syncronization improve. Actually I am not using ApproximateTimeSynchronizer.

---

Originally posted by [Alessandro Melino](https://answers.ros.org/users/52370/alessandro-melino/) with karma: 113 on 2021-10-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1